# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: wampserver

I am currenty using internet using putty and i am on proxy network. My wamp server is showing orange icon. I checked that apache services is not running, and i tried to run that service explicitly but didnot work.I have IIS Server installed too.Please help

```
 Error:   This service didnot respond to the start vor control request in timely fashion.
```

This error is given on explicit start of service

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I added the error.

Comment: IIS is a web server and therefore will be using TCP port 80. Apache is a web server and therefore will be TRYING to use TCP port 80. If IIS gets it first (IIS is probably started as boot time) then Apache will not be able to get to port 80 as is cannot be shared.

Comment: The simplest answer is put WAMPServer on a seperate PC.

Comment: If you can stop IIS while you are developing on WAMPServer then that is a good idea.

Comment: If non of the above are possible, then change the port that Apache is listening on to something other than port 80

Comment: I got error. Sql server was causing problem